# Shell Scripting: Function with multi-line argument as an argument to another function

Tags: bash, shell

I have a function which takes another function as an argument and perform some operation.
e.g.

```
processFunc()
{
    Func=$1
    ...
}
```

Now the problem is when i am passing a function which also accept multi line variable as argument.
e.g.

```
VAL="1\n2\n3\n4"
Func1()
{
    VAL=$1
    ...
}
```

Now, there is no problem when I call direct function `Func1()`
e.g.

```
VAL2=`Func1 "$VAL"`
```

But an issue arises when I try to call `proccessFunc()`
e.g.

```
VAL3=`processFunc 'Func1 "$VAL"'`   #Here is the problem...
```

Need help how to resolve the above problem.

**Test code**

```
#! /bin/bash
#set -x
func1()
{
    VAL1="$1"
    echo "$VAL1" ok
    for i in $VAL1
    do
        echo $i
        sleep 1
    done
}

func2()
{
    VALFUN="$1"
    TIME=$2
    COUNTER=1
    while [ $COUNTER -le $TIME ]
    do
         # clear
         $VALFUN
         sleep 2
         COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
    done
}

func3()
{
    echo a
    echo b
    echo c
}

#### Main #####
LOCALVAL="`echo -e "123\nabc\nxyz"`"
#echo "$LOCALVAL"
echo "func1"
func1 "$LOCALVAL"
echo "func2 with func3"
func2 "func3" 3
echo "func2 wth func1"
func2 "func1 "$LOCALVAL"" 3
```

Error I am getting is:

```
./test.sh: line 18: [: abc: integer expression expected
```

Comment: can you please state what error/problem you are facing ?

Comment: I've edited your code into your question — I saw that you tried.  Please check that it is now OK. When preparing code for SO, indent it with spaces (not tabs) and usually 4 spaces per indent level (but that is up to you). Copy'n'paste the code into the edit box, select it and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it as code. That's basically what I did for you. Beware back-quotes in shell. They're confusing with SO Markdown. Also, in general, use `$(…)` instead of back-quotes for [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

Comment: What is the 'abc' over here ??

Comment: abc is the second line in variable LOCALVAL
------ the code is trying to eval the variable

Comment: So what you want to do.. if I am not wrong from your script you want to pass the func1 as a argument to func2 and call func2 from some other func?

Comment: Yes you can say that, also since in actual my func1 output is complicated and contains spacial char like "#, | and -" which further create problem.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that be great if you use the output from the Func1 and use it for the processFunc

So your code would be :

```
VAL="1\n2\n3\n4"
VAL2=Func1 "$VAL"
```

Where Func1 would be :

```
Func1()
{
 VAL=$1
 ...
}
```

And then calling the processFunc as

```
VAL3=processFunc "$VAL"
```

Hope this helps.

Or Else what I suppose is that you are passing a string value where your shell is expecting a string.
And I believe the code should be :

```
a=123\nabc\nxyz
LOCALVAL = echo $a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
VAL3="processFunc Func1 $VAL"
$VAL3
```